# Выбрать несколько вариантов в тесте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте! 
есть [тест](http://kaptn.ru/ccna), у которого ответы обрабатываются с помощью jQuery.
С вопросами, которые требуют один вариант ответа нет никаких нареканий, но выбрать несколько просто нет возможности.

Собственно, вопрос: как сделать выбор нескольких дивов?
Исходный код на [GitHub](http://github.com/vikapitoshka/ccna)

Answer (score 1):

Единственный правильный ответ на вопрос: `<input type="radio" ...`.

Несколько приемлемых ответов на один вопрос: `<input type="checkbox" ...`.

Comment: Да, это то понятно, подумала, мало ли есть другой способ